# Undefined protocol in the URL cell

Tags: c#, infragistics, ultrawingrid

I have a `UltraGridCell` with style equal to `Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.ColumnStyle.URL` and add my own handler to `UltraGrid.MouseClick` so that I can open a new tab if the URL columns is clicked.

Nothing is wrong if the URL column is of the value "ABCDE". It looks like a URL link in the cell with underline and blue color (turns purple after click). It just like a URL link in the browser.

The issue is that if the content is of the value like "ABC:DE". It turns out it complains that there is an undefined protocol is calling. Just like you enter "ABC://DE" at the IE URL bar.

[image]

After checking in the debug mode, it looks like that this should be called by UltraGrid internally.
Hence, my question is: Is there any way for me to disable this default behavior?

Any help is highly appreciated.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When you set the column style to `Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.ColumnStyle.URL` the editor of the column becomes `Infragistics.Win.FormattedLinkLabel.FormattedLinkEditor`. This editor has `LinkClicked` event. In the event handler you can get `OpenLink` property of the event argument and set it to `false`. This will suppress link opening. To do so, first get the editor in the `InitializeLayout` event:

```
private void UltraGrid1_InitializeLayout(object sender, InitializeLayoutEventArgs e)
{
    // get the column you will set up
    var column = e.Layout.Bands[YOUR_BAND_INDEX].Columns[YOUR_COLUMN_INDEX];

    // set the style of the column (you already did this)
    column.Style = Infragistics.Win.UltraWinGrid.ColumnStyle.URL;

    // get the editor after set the column style and handle LinkClicked event
    var editor = column.Editor as FormattedLinkEditor;
    editor.LinkClicked += this.Editor_LinkClicked;
}
```

Then in `LinkClicked` event stop link opening:

```
private void Editor_LinkClicked(object sender, Infragistics.Win.FormattedLinkLabel.LinkClickedEventArgs e)
{
    e.OpenLink = false;
}
```

Comment: Thanks so much, your solution is just perfect.